How to remove hint text from TextField?
Hello I can't remove this hint text from the date input in React:

I've tried setting a default value, as well as setting an empty placeholder property for this input, both didn't work for me. I want this to display as an empty input, no hint. How can I do this in React? Thanks
Input definition:
<Grid item xs={6}>
    <Controller
        name={"periodTo-" + input.index}
        control={input.form}
        render={({field: {onChange, value}, fieldState: {error}}) => (
            <div style={{marginTop: "10px"}}>
                <InputLabel>end date</InputLabel>
                <TextField
                            style={{width:"100%"}}
                            value={value} onChange={onChange} type="date" placeholder="" defaultValue={{}}/>
            </div>
        )}
    />
</Grid>


It looks like you are using MaterialUI component. In this case if your input is a date you could simply use the  component which is suitable for these inputs

Try using the inputProps as last property of TextField
<DatePicker
  inputFormat="tt.mm.jjjj"
  label="Basic example"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} inputProps={{placeholder: ""}} />}
/>


Datepicker doesn't work for me, I have to strictly use "TextField type date"
